# How to prevent MongoDB from locking

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got a write query that reads in from a source very minute or so. But I also have an application that needs to read from that database. I don't need that new data that second.

The write query is locking the database preventing the (normally fast) read query from running.

here is the result of currentOP();

```
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "opid" : 547909,
            "active" : true,
            "secs_running" : 0,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(104962),
            "op" : "insert",
            "ns" : "nb.article_raw",
            "insert" : {
                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
            },
            "client" : "<<IP>>:52548",
            "desc" : "conn10993",
            "threadId" : "0x7ef7ebfb2700",
            "connectionId" : 10993,
            "locks" : {
                "^" : "w",
                "^nb" : "W"
            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 0,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(0),
                    "w" : NumberLong(581)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(0),
                    "w" : NumberLong(15467)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "opid" : 546673,
            "active" : true,
            "secs_running" : 48,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(48720118),
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "nb.article_raw",
            "query" : {
                "id" : {
                    "$nin" : [ ]
                },
                "hasCompleteImage" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                },
                "date" : {
                    "$gt" : ISODate("2015-07-10T00:54:35Z")
                }
            },
            "client" : "100.36.81.202:60791",
            "desc" : "conn10979",
            "threadId" : "0x7f55de5ae700",
            "connectionId" : 10979,
            "locks" : {
                "^nb" : "R"
            },
            "waitingForLock" : true,
            "numYields" : 6611,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(19244958),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(18701993),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas how I can write the first query so that it doesn't lock?  The write code writes over iterations of a loop one at a time via nodeJS Mongo drive `collection.insertOne`

Insertion code loop

```
promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
        collection.insertOne(obj, {}, function(err) {
            if(err) {

            }
            resolve();
        });
        z++;
}));
```

Which is inside a foreach over the objects.

Comment: Show the code, there likely is a better way to execute it.

Comment: @BlakesSeven It's just a loop over objects doing a `collection.insertOne`. The reads are just `collection.find` screenshot of the loop http://cl.ly/image/3s2h0T361V26

Comment: Code included in your question would be nicer. Cut and paste text, so people don't need to squint at images. Or follow external links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are a few things you can do here, but generally you are running up against "architecture" in both your application and server distribution. This means there are a few things ( or maybe all ) to consider.

I'm just going to cover the basics here without going into the "Buy more RAM" or "Get a bigger instance" game, and really concentrating on the "scaling out" aspects before "scaling up".

### Smarter Inserts

---

Calling `.insertOne()` over and over for a list of items is not really efficient, and depending on the size of the list could really "lock up" your database.

No matter what you are using for actual resolution then I think you really should look at the Bulk Operations APi instead. Writes are not sent inidivually but in "batches". So in the simplesest form:

```
var bulk = collection.inititalizeUnorderedBulkOp();

listOfThings.forEach(function(obj) {
    bulk.insert(obj);
});

// But actually sends to server here
bulk.execute(function(err,response) {

});
```

For really large lists, you probably don't want all of that in memory for either the list to process or the "batch", so there should be some throttling there.

The point is, sending 1000 inserts to the server at once is better than 1000 requests and 1000 responses, which is a lot of trafffic. Also this allows a little more control where a "batch" of operations is only obtaining a lock. There is a bit more "yield" room in there for other operations than if you are repeatedly "banging" on the server with request after request.

### Possibly use secondary reads

---

Since you say you can live with queries not being on the "absolute latest" data, then having a ReplicaSet architecture ( which you "should" have in production anyway ) allows you to defer your "reads" to the secondaries.

While the secondaries are "following the updates" they are not doing so "just as hard" as the PRIMARY which is accepting all the initial writes is doing so. So this allows a bit more headroom here.

### Shard to Distribute

---

You have "hot spots" here where you are basically overloading on both read and write operations simultaneously. Sharding allows you to consider spreading either the "write load", by distrbuting writes accross shards or the "read load" by either taking advantage of the "writes" possibly not occuring on the same "shard" as the "read" is being sourced from at that point in time, or by generally doing a "scatter gather" in it's search and evenly hitting multiple shards.

### Update Storage Engine, or at least consider where your data is

---

So ultimately you are running up against "collection level locking" or "database level locking" depending on the available version. A clear change would be upgrade to MongoDB 3.x and use the [Wired tiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#storage-wiredtiger) engine which has "document level locking".

Failing that being an option, then at least consider the lock level and either:

- try to write to another collection than what you are reading from and only "periodically" update the "reading collection"
- Or, do exactly the same thing at the database container level.

---

Everything here is a variation on the same theme, which is "reduce the overhead" and "distrubute the load" where possible. So I would go for at least implementing batch insertion first, as there is always something to gain from that.

Then look at the other options here ( not necessarily in the order presented, but replica set before sharding ) and try to get the level of "conflict" between your writes down.

Also look at "indexes", if you have a lot of them it will slow down writes. It is very common for people to index more than they actually need to, so be aware of that as well.

Comment: Hell yea! This was an amazing answer. What's the difference between sharding and replica set? I know I can google that, and I will, but I'd love your take on it

Comment: @SeanClark That my friend is a "whole" different question. So ask questions about it if you feel the need, but seriously search teh interwebs first. Short snack though: A ReplicaSet is "physical nodes" containing redundant copies of data for HighAvailability, but can be used as an alternate read source ( across nodes ) if your appllication tolerates delayed updates of data. A Shard is a "piece" of data "segmented" into ranges by a chosen key range. It is a "logical" node comprised of "phyiscal nodes" and usually ReplicaSets.But read more.